# How I can covert it to unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string:

```
u'\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbe \xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd1\x86 \xd0\xb2\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd1\x85'
```

It contain сyrillic text. How I can convert it on Python 2.7.x to unicode string with сyrillic symbols e.g.

```
u'видео палец вверх'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encode with `latin1` encoding:

```
>>> s = u'\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbe \xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd1\x86 \xd0\xb2\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd1\x85'

>>> print s.encode('latin1')
видео палец вверх
```

Comment: When I use your code in my Windows system it only displays garbage...

Comment: Isn't that the wrong way round? Because the original is UTF-8 encoded and just mislabeled as unicode. Dropping the `u` prefix and using `s.decode('utf-8')` should do the trick. As printed it probably only works when your current encoding is `utf-8` and hence your string literals are interpreted in that encoding.

Comment: @dhke Maybe, but it seems that OP is dealing with a pre-encoded string. So you can reverse the whole process with encoding on `latin1`.

Comment: @Kasramvd ... and TIL  that I can coerce improperly marked unicode strings to byte strings with `.encode('latin1')`.

Answer (score 1):

That `u` prefix on the original string seems wrong. Looks like the characters are utf-8 encoded, so this should be a simple (byte) string:

```
# no u'' prefix:
s = '\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbe \xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd1\x86 \xd0\xb2\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd1\x85'
# string is utf-8, decode it to unicode
u = s.decode('utf-8')
# this only works when your terminal charset is properly set up
print u
>>>> видео палец вверх
```

If you got that string from elsewhere, it's string type is wrong. In this case, you can follow Serge Ballesta's and Kasramvd's advice and force it back to a byte string by encoding it with `latin1` encoding:

```
s = u'\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbe \xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd1\x86 \xd0\xb2\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd1\x85'
# force encode with latin 1 and then properly decode it using utf-8
u = s.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
print u
>>>> видео палец вверх
```

Comment: If the initial value does contain the `u` prefix, you can first convert it to bytes with a latin1 encoding: `ut.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')`

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yeah, but if OP gets an unicode string with UTF-8 encoding in place of a byte string, something's already wrong further up the chain.